# Keypad Disappear on Orientation Change

Tags: android, android-webview

In the Android Web view when i change the orientation the keypad disappears, is there any way to prevent the keypad disappear on the orientation change. Please find my code for the reference,

Android-Manifest.xml

```
  <activity
        android:name="com.alere.mya.WebContainerActivity"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:scrollbarAlwaysDrawVerticalTrack="true"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateUnchanged" android:launchMode="singleInstance">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Activity,

public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {

```
    ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
    // Checks the orientation of the screen
    if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
        imageView.setImageDrawable(this.getResources().getDrawable(
                R.drawable.default_landscape));
        Log.d("on Landscape Orientation", webview.toString());
        webview.loadUrl(MyaConstant.orientationLandscape);

    } else if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT) {
        Log.d("on Portrait Orientation", webview.toString());
        imageView.setImageDrawable(this.getResources().getDrawable(
                R.drawable.m_logo));
        webview.loadUrl(MyaConstant.orientationPortrait);
    }
    if (onGraph) {
        getCurrentOrientation();

    }
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);

}
```

What is wrong here. Any one can suggest me?.

I tried with the super.onConfigurationChanged as the first to the last line. still no response.

Comment: I think you have covered everything there. You will just have to give up on that one.

Comment: Which one should have to give Up philip. Its not working for me. apart from these i have so many receivers and services should i include in any order?

Comment: Still its not working for me?